# How can I have ssh-add query pass (the password manager) for passwords when it adds identities at startup?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, scripting

I have (and need) multiple ssh keys. I often need all of them in a session and I configure ssh so that it automatically selects the right one for the right server, so I thought I would write a script which adds them all on login. I put this in `.profile`:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/list/of/ ~/paths/to/keys
```

That works fine, in that it attempts to add the keys on login and asks me for the passwords using `ssh-askpass` (note lowercase: I mean the [program](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-askpass.1), not the environment variable).

However, I also use `pass` to store my passwords, including those for my various ssh keys. I know the password for `pass`'s gpg authentication, but of course I don't memorise all of the passwords stored in pass, which makes the ssh prompt for those passwords useless.

How can I have `ssh-add` ask `pass` for the passwords for the different passwords (and then have `pass` prompt me for the gpg authenication password, rather than ssh prompt me for separate ssh passwords)?

The passwords in `pass` are not named the same as the ssh id files, but are named in a pattern-similar way (e.g for an ssh id `id_rsa_personal` the corresponding password would be (~/.password-store/)`ssh/personal`).

Perhaps a raw gpg script bypassing the pass wrapper entirely would be better?

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```bsh
if [[ -v PASS_PATH ]]; then
    pass $PASS_PATH
    exit $?
fi

for I in \
    "$HOME/.ssh/id_key_1_ed25519;your/path/in/pass/for/key1" \
    "$HOME/.ssh/id_key_2_rsa;your/path/in/pass/for/key1"
do
    SSHKEYPATH=${I%;*}
    PASS=${I#*;}
    SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE="force" SSH_ASKPASS="$0" PASS_PATH="$PASS" ssh-add $SSHKEYPATH < /dev/null
done
```

This is mostly based on [How to make ssh-add read passphrase from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13034313/2256700) and using `< /dev/null` to force `ssh-add` to really call the askpass program.